# Android IDE Doesn't create Main.java or XML

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ide

I'm using the newest version of the Android IDE which seems to be Eclipse fully integrated with the Android tools.  On the creation of a new file (New > Android Application Project) I follow the steps on creating the files.  I am following a tutorial that uses an older version of eclipse, and when they create a new project, under 'src' there is a java.main file.  This is missing when I create mine, along with the main.xml.  I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new Android Project with New > Android Application Project, you specify the Application Name, Project Name, and Package Name.  On the next screen you must have "Create Activity" checked.  Select the defaults and then you will have a new Activity called "MainActivity" under your src folder in the package name you set.  The layout xml file will be found in res > layout folder.